# A more effective method of handling this?

Tags: java, math

I am currently working on an extension for an online game in Java. I am currently handling teleportation to know whether a player has teleported a certain distance that can be from the `distance` parameter.

The thing is, I know this is a super intensive task on the CPU, even if I did attempt to offload it from the main thread.

Would there be any more efficient way of handling this, or would I basically have to restructure the entire thing?

`this.square` is just Math.pow();, `this.sqrt` is Math.sqrt();,
`this.hypot` is as following:

```
default double hypot(double... numbers) {
        double squaredSum = 0.0;

        int length = numbers.length;
        int count = 0;

        while (count < length) {
            double number = numbers[count];
            squaredSum += Math.pow(number, 2.0);
            ++count;
        }
        return this.sqrt(squaredSum);
    }
```

This is how I am checking whether the player teleported

```
public boolean anyNear(CustomLocation location, double distance) {
    if (!this.locations.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<TeleportSnapshot> iterator = this.locations.iterator();

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            TeleportSnapshot teleport = iterator.next();

            double deltaX = location.getX() - teleport.x;
            double deltaY = location.getY() - teleport.y;
            double deltaZ = location.getZ() - teleport.z;

            while (!(this.hypot(deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ) < this.sqrt(this.square(distance)))) {
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    teleport = iterator.next();
                    deltaX = location.getX() - teleport.x;
                    deltaY = location.getY() - teleport.y;
                    deltaZ = location.getZ() - teleport.z;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: How long is numbers.length? This doesn't seem like something that would be that CPU intensive.

Comment: this.sqrt(this.square(distance))      this seems odd.  why are taking the sqrt of a square

Comment: You could do all the distances as sqaures, so you don't have to sqrt()

Comment: Why do you create a manual loop and even such a non-idiomatic `while` loop instead of the standard `for` loop? Just `for(double number: numbers) squaredSum += number*number;` does the job. Starting with Java 9, you may use `for(double number: numbers) squaredSum = Math.fma(number, number, squaredSum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with David Zimmerman, you should probably not use the square root in your computation.

Instead of doing

```
sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2) < sqrt(distance^2),
```

you can use:

```
dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 < distance^2
```

which is much more cpu friendly. The name of your auxiliary function for the hypothenuse wouldn't fit anymore though...